# Proving convergence/divergence via the ratio test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider the series
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{-3^k\cdot k!}{k^k}$$

Using the ratio test, the expression $\frac{|a_{k+1}|}{|a_k|}$ is calculated as:

$$\frac{3^{k+1}\cdot (k+1)!}{(k+1)^{k+1}}\cdot \frac{k^k}{3^k\cdot k!}=\frac{3}{(k+1)^{k}}\cdot {k^k}=3\cdot \frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{k}}=3\cdot \left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^k$$

How to continue?

Comment: Or maybe divergence. Note that $\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^k$ has limit $e\lt 3$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I got $(\frac{k}{k+1})^k$

Comment: Sure, I wrote down the reciprocal because the limit for that is more familiar. So the limit of the ratio is $3/e$, bad news for convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}3\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^k=\lim_{k\to\infty}3\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{k}}\right)^k=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{3}{\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k}=\frac{3}{e}>1$.

Comment: Can you explain the first equality?

Comment: Yes, I am dividing the top and bottom of the fraction by k.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} 3\cdot \bigg(\frac{k}{k+1}\bigg)^k = \lim_{k\to\infty} 3\cdot \bigg(1 - \frac{1}{k+1}\bigg)^k = 3\cdot \lim_{k\to\infty}\bigg(1-\frac{1}{k}\bigg)^k = 3\cdot e^{-1}$$

Comment: if it is minus so it is $e^{-1}$?

Comment: $(1 +\frac{a}{x})^x \to e^a\text{ as }x\to\infty$

Answer (score 0):

the limit is $\frac{3}{e}>1$ thus the sum doesn't converge.

Comment: Yes, it may diverge, sorry edited the question.
How do we get $e$?

Comment: @gbox state the definition of $e$.

Comment: $\lim_{k \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k=e$

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have problem on $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{k}{k+1}^k$

Let
$$y=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{k}{k+1}^k$$
Take $\ln$ on both sides,
$$\ln y = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln k - \ln (k+1)}{k^{-1}}$$
Use L'Hopital's rule,
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln k - \ln (k+1)}{k^{-1}} = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} -k^2(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}) = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \frac{-k}{k+1} = -1$$
Therefore,
$$y = e^{-1}$$
The ratio test shows this diverges.

Answer (score 0):

$$\log L=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty }k\log(1-\frac{1}{k+1})=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\log(1-\frac{1}{k+1})}{\frac{1}{k}}$$
by using Lopital rule
$$\log L=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\frac{\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}}{1-\frac{1}{k+1}}}{\frac{-1}{k^2}}=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty }\frac{-k^2}{(k^2+1)(1-\frac{1}{k+1})}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty }\frac{-1}{(1+\frac{1}{k^2})(1-\frac{1}{1+k})}=-1$$
hence the limit $$\frac{3}{e}>1$$